# Draw a portion of a line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, drawing, line

I just wanna draw a portion of a line. I'll try to be more specific.

[image]

Now I wanna see just a portion of the red line..but I don't know how to do it in Matlab. I wanna show like a little portion around the red dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `plot` command:

```
  x = [0 3];
  y = [1 -4];
  plot(x,y,'r');
```

In order to draw 2 shapes together, use `hold on`:

```
  x = -2*pi:0.01:2*pi;
  y = sin(x);
  plot(x,y,'k');
  hold on;
  x = [0 3];
  y = [1 -4];
  plot(x,y,'r');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `line` to draw what you need. Say you want to draw a point going from (0,1) to (3,-4), type:

```
line ([0 3], [1 -4])
```